# Vagrant: easy way to define custom Chef service or boot script

Tags: service, chef-infra, vagrant, init.d, cookbook

I have a Vagrant project which defines a couple of VMs. On one of them I need to run some commands to tune kernel parameters, download a file from a remote location, and start a daemon. Currently I define in a `cookbooks/*/recipes/default.rb`:

```
execute "sudo tune-kernel-parameter"
execute "curl http://something/ > /tmp/some-file"
execute "sudo some-daemon --config /tmp/some-file"
```

which all works fine when I first `vagrant up`. But of course if the machine reboots, none of these commands are run again, since they are not part of any init script.

I suppose I could always run `vagrant reload` to reboot a VM, but I want it to just be able to reboot directly. In other words, have a persisted “service”.

Now *some* of the commands given above (kernel tuning) could be replaced by modifications to files in `/etc`, if I wanted to spend the time to look up the right syntax for those files (after I have already done the work of verifying that the immediate commands do what I want). And for others (starting a daemon) I may be able to use a predefined service, i.e. an Ubuntu package defining a service that I can configure in `/etc` and start using the `service` resource.

But then there are idiosyncratic commands like the download mentioned above (which must be done *before* the daemon starts). Presumably I could use the `template` resource to define a script in `/etc/init.d/` and then use `service` to start it upon provisioning (though [Chef, how to run a template that creates a init.d script before the service is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938314/chef-how-to-run-a-template-that-creates-a-init-d-script-before-the-service-is-c/9941971#9941971) implies that this is even more work than it sounds).

But is there no standard way of simply asking for a short inline script to be run both during provisioning and also upon subsequent reboots? Something in between `execute` and `service`, e.g.

```
init_script <<-END
    sudo tune-kernel-parameter
    curl http://something/ > /tmp/some-file
    sudo some-daemon --config /tmp/some-file
END
```

(I am assuming that the script is idempotent, i.e. it is OK for a `vagrant provision` to run a modified version again in the same VM session; if I need to `killall some-daemon` first, that is easy.)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use `/etc/rc.local` for that:

```
file "/etc/rc.local" do
  content <<-EOC
    sudo tune-kernel-parameter
    curl http://something/ > /tmp/some-file
    sudo some-daemon --config /tmp/some-file
  EOC
  mode 0755
  notifies :run, "execute[rc.local]"
end

execute "rc.local"
  command "/etc/rc.local"
  action :nothing
end
```

The `execute` block only declares a `resource` but does `:nothing` with it. When `file` runs, *if it modifies* the file on disk, it then `notifies` the `execute` resource to `:run`.